# De onde vem a gíria "zica"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, girias

No Brasil, é comum o uso da gíria "zica". Veja alguns exemplos:

1. > Estou numa *zica* danada. (no sentido de azar)
2. > O show de amanhã vai ser *zica*! (no sentido de ser bom)

É interessante que essa gíria pode ter dois significados. Seria interessante saber de onde ela vem, e se é utilizada em outros países também.

Comment: Ainda não chegou até a mim.  A única zica que conheço é a doença viral.  Ou então a Dona Zica.

Comment: https://www.significados.com.br/zica/ Eu também acredito que veio de "ziquizira".

Comment: Nunca ouvi _zica_ no sentido de algo bom! Podes elencar alguns usos publicos dessa vertente?

Comment: Aqui no sul, ouço também zika como bicicleta.

ex: Vou pegar minha zika e ir para casa.

Comment: @gmauch Na cidade de São Paulo, em situações *totalmente* informais, já ouvi a palavra zica sendo usada como adjetivo que caracteriza algo positivo. Por exemplo, "o cara é zica", ou "esse moleque é zica" quando alguém é muito habilidoso para alguma coisa (seduzir mulheres, empinar moto, etc). Não sei se é regional, mas acredito que, com esse sentido positivo, seja uma gíria usada principalmente por pessoas das periferias. Como um exemplo, deixo [esse vídeo de um menino que é zika na capoeira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P62RbRrgmOA). Obs.: Não sei se a grafia correta é zika ou zica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *zica* diferente do vírus *zika* é uma gíria, com possível origem africana como [muitas palavras que compõem o português brasileiro](https://www.geledes.org.br/palavras-de-origem-africana-no-vocabulario-brasileiro/).

No entanto as origens são confusas e o processo evolutivo do significado original até o que vemos hoje é desconhecido.

Logo encontrei alguns sites explicando *zica* como uma contração da gíria *ziquizira*, que pode ser tanto [*doença inexplicável*](http://palavraseorigens.blogspot.com/2011/01/zica-posso-tirar.html) e também a palavra *kijila* como a origem da *zica*.

Tentando seguir pelo caminho da palavra *kijila* em um pequeno dicionário [português quimbundu](https://sites.google.com/site/kilombokakongo/portugues-kimbundu):

> kijila: abstenção, proibição.

O sentido de azar talvez se encaixaria como restrição, proibição a determinada situação.

Já o sentido bom da palavra *zica* possa ter relação também com a proibição, como uma [letra de música](https://www.robertocarlos.com/letras/ilegal-imoral-ou-engorda/) diz:

> será que tudo que eu gosto
>   é ilegal, é imoral
>   ou engorda...